# Windows batch script - find string and echo everything after

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm creating a summary audit file, and one of the files I am scanning through is 300-1000+ pages. The information I am trying to extract to this audit file is ALWAYS the last 3 pages or so.

So while I am a little familiar with the findstr or find function, I don't know how to return EVERYTHING after that information is found. Help?

Using that logic then how do I get everything after Balance Report?

```
FINDSTR /l "BALANCE REPORT" EXAMPLE.REPORT 1>NUL 2>&1 && (
ECHO WHAT DO I PUT HERE??? >> NightlyAudit.txt
) || (
ECHO No Balance Report Found! >> NightlyAudit.txt
)
```

Comment: You need to provide us with what you are familiar with, code wise, then seek help with that.

Comment: Made edit to OP

Comment: You need to be very specific about what you are trying to search for in the example report. The example you have now provided is searching within the content for the case sensitive term BALANCE and the case sensitive term REPORT.

Comment: Both `find` and `findstr` return the whole lines containing matches (or all the others in case switch `/V` is specified); if you need to output the match plus everything behind that in the same line you need to split off the part in front of the match programmatically by some criteria which you need to define and to tell us; if you are interested in all *lines* starting from the one containing the match and all after, you could possibly add the `/N` switch so every returned line is prefixed with its line number; these numbers can then be used to determine what to output and what not...

Comment: Are you looking for every line after the 'only' match or every line including the 'only' matched line. Also are you specifically looking for the string 'BALANCE REPORT' but not 'BALANCE REPORTS', 'IMBALANCE REPORT' or 'IMBALANCE REPORTING'. Is that search term on it's own on a line, does it start or end the line etc. Also does the string have to be case sensitive? Making sure of your search criteria will certainly ensure that any work done of the body of the rest of the code is not over engineered or wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your FINDSTR search may be incorrect - `"BALANCE REPORT"` will match any line that contains `BALANCE` or `REPORT`. I suspect you want to match the literal string `BALANCE REPORT`, in which case you need to use `/c:"BALANCE REPORT"`.

You can add the /N option to get the line number that matches, parse out the value with FOR /F, and then use MORE with the +n to skip the appropriate number of lines.

The following will write out all lines that come *after* the matching line

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /nlc:"BALANCE REPORT" example.report'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
if not defined skip (
  echo BALANCE REPORT not found
  exit /b 1
)
more +%skip% example.report >NightlyAudit.txt
```

If you want to include the matching line in the output, then you must subtract one. If the first line happens to match, then you don't want to skip any lines, but MORE does not allow +0, so the logic requires a bit more than simply subtracting 1.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "skip="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in (
  'findstr /nlc:"BALANCE REPORT" example.report'
) do if not defined skip set skip=%%N
if not defined skip (
  echo BALANCE REPORT not found
  exit /b 1
)
set /a skip-=1
if %skip% equ 0 (
  set "skip="
) else (
  set "skip=+%skip%"
)
more %skip% example.report >NightlyAudit.txt
```

Note that MORE will convert any [Tab] characters into a series of spaces. There is one other potential problem. I'm not sure that MORE can skip more than 64k lines, and if your source file has 1000 pages of 60 lines each, then you may be dangerously close to the limit.

So it is possible that MORE may not work for you, in which case you need an alternative. Here is one way to do it with pure batch, but it is relatively slow, and has a limit of ~8190 bytes per line.

Substitute the following for the MORE command to print all lines after the match:

```
...
>NightlyAudit.txt (
  for /f "skip=%skip% delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" example.report') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

If you want to include the matching line, then the computation of the SKIP variable changes a bit, as does the FOR /F options. FOR /F also does not allow skip=0, but the syntax is a bit different than with MORE.

```
...
set /a skip-=1
if %skip% equ 0 (
  set "skip="
) else (
  set "skip=skip=%skip%"
)
>NightlyAudit.txt (
  for /f "%skip% delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" example.report') do (
  ...
```

---

It is pretty easy to accomplish your goal with a single read of your input if you use some other scripting language. For example, you could use JScript with CSCRIPT.

For example, the following can be used to write all lines after the match:

**writeAfterMatch.js**

```
var str, go=0;
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  str=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
  if (go) WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(str);
  if (!go) if (str.indexOf(WScript.Arguments(0))>0) go=1;
}
```

**usage**

```
cscript //nologo writeAfterMatch.js "BALANCE REPORT" <example.report >NightlyAudit.txt
```

Just reverse the order of a couple lines and you can include the matching line:

**writeAfterMatchInclusive.js**

```
var str, go=0;
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  str=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
  if (!go) if (str.indexOf(WScript.Arguments(0))>0) go=1;
  if (go) WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(str);
}
```

**usage**

```
cscript //nologo writeAfterMatchInclusive.js "BALANCE REPORT" <example.report >NightlyAudit.txt
```

---

Another option is to use my [JREPL.BAT text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to solve the problem with minimal code. JREPL is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available by issuing `JREPL /??` from the command line.

It may look intimidating because there are so many options. But the solution is actually rather simple.

The following one liner will write out all lines *after* the match

```
jrepl "BALANCE REPORT" "go++;$0" /l /j /jendln "if(go<2)$txt=false;if(go)go++" /jbeg "go=0" /f example.report /o NightlyAudit.txt
```

This simpler variation will include the matching line:

```
jrepl "BALANCE REPORT" "go=1;$0" /l /j /jendln "if(!go)$txt=false" /jbeg "go=0" /f example.report /o NightlyAudit.txt
```

If you use the JREPL command within your own batch script, then you would need to use CALL JREPL.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you! I'm just learning these languages and the cscript is working perfect. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone coming on this, the first code sample does not include the `/N` which is required for the `for` loop to work correctly.  Those `findstr` commands should include be `findstr /N ...`.  Great answer otherwise.

Comment: @ByronWall - OMG, I talk about the /N option in my text, and then forgot to include it in the code!!! Thanks for the comment. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 2):

The general structure is:

```
FINDSTR [switch(es)] [string(s)] [source] 1>NUL 2>&1 && (
    [successful commands]
) || (
    [unsuccessful commands]
)
```

Comment: updated OP again using your  FINDSTR code. Thanks for the help @Compo